# Making my website mobile friendly - Google mobile friendly test

Tags: wordpress, mobile, seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

I've been busy building a mobile friendly version of my website at http://mobilereactor.co.uk/ so I thought i'd test it at https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

My website is now mobile friendly as far as I can see on my mobile and iPad which switches from the main theme if it detects mobile or ipad etc to my mobile theme.

The thing is google says it's not mobile friendly and that i'm blocking robots.txt?

```
This page uses one resource which is blocked by robots.txt. The results and screenshot may be incorrect.
```

Am I doing something wrong - I'm using wordpress and Any Mobile Theme Plugin which enables me to switch to a different theme if mobile is detected.

How can I make Google happy any suggestions or advice.

Comment: Why don't you write responsive css code rather than using a mobile theme switcher?

Comment: I did consider that but I thought it would be better to have a mobile theme I may actually do this as it will probably work out better

Answer (score 0):

Ay,

First, can you test your website with https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ ?

You will be able to see all errors and fix them. After that, recheck you website with https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/.